# How to handle if isSelected() always returns false

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

There is a checkbox
When checkbox is not clicked

[image]

and when checkbox is clicked

[image]

Now I can see that ::after tag is the difference.
My real problem I am not able to use isSelected() method with the chechbox that return always false.

Source Code is

```
public void deselectUserManagement() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("check if UM selected");
    //boolean userMgmtSelected=userManagementCheckBox.isSelected();
    if(userManagementCheckBox.isSelected())
    {
        System.out.println("deselected UM");
        userManagementCheckBox.click();
        System.out.println("UM deselected");
        handelPermissionRevokeAlert();
    }

}
```

locator is

```
//b[text()='User Management']//following-sibling::span
```

Comment: please show us the code you've already tried!

Comment: if(userManagementCheckBox.isSelected())
        {
            System.out.println("deselected UM");
            userManagementCheckBox.click();
            System.out.println("UM deselected");
            handelPermissionRevokeAlert();
        }

Comment: conditions get false anyways.

Comment: locator is  : //b[text()='User Management']//following-sibling::span

Comment: update your question with the source code that I can identify the issue including predefined functions if any

Comment: I have update question with my function and locator. Let me know if anything else needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findElements()` methods that will return a list, and you can check for size, if size is `> 0` then do some-foo stuff, it it's 0 then select it.

or

you can wrap your code inside try-catch block like this :

```
try{
Boolean status = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[text()='User Management']//following-sibling::span")).isSelected();
System.out.println(status)
if(status){
  // do some stuff when check box is selected here
   }
}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("bad code")
}
```

Comment: The thing is here status is always false.

Comment: Did you try the above solution ? Did you try findElements or try catch ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but that not works as there is no exception occurs

Comment: Did some reserch and found.....As a related note, this type of selection indicator is not handled by
Selenium isSelected() methods, etc. because it's not a true/real
checkbox/radio button selection. It's mimicked to look real using
javascript code and the actual elements are something else, not even real
checkboxes, radio buttons etc. like div elements. You have to be aware of
that when automating your application.....but no Idea how to implement this